# High response time with high throughput?

Tags: performance, web-applications, performance-testing, throughput, response-time

Can there be systems where it has high throughput but also high response times. I believe it can be possible. Consider the system which gets 100 hits
per second(HPS) and response time is 2 sec. It generates the throughput of 100 QPS.  So we can say it is high throughput(100 QPS) system but low response time(2 sec).
Is that correct ?

But at the same time if throughput(say 80) is lesser than HPS(say 100) then it means sometime down the line system will choke as outlet rate is lesser than inlet rate . Right ?

Now other way round, can there be system with low response time  and also low throughput ? I believe that is also possible but not able to think a 
release scenario?

So bottom line is we have to look both stats together i.e. throughput and response time as it is not mandatory if one is good another is also good at same 
time?

Answer (score 0):

In ideal world it would be

1. Response time is always the same
2. Throughput increased by the same factor as load increases, for example:

   - with 100 virtual users you have 100 requests per second
   - with 200 virtual users you have 200 requests per second
   - etc.

In real world at some point when you increase the load throughput will not increase, instead of it response time will increase hence the system will not be able to serve 200 users as fast as 100 users. This is known as [performance bottleneck](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing)

More information:

- [What is the Relationship Between Users and Hits Per Second?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-relationship-between-users-and-hits-second/)
- [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)